# How to queue Laravel 5.7 "email verification" email sending

Tags: laravel, queue, email-verification, laravel-5.7

Laravel 5.7 included "email verification" feature works well but not async email sending (during user register or resend link page) is not ideal.

Is there any way to send the email verification email through a queue without rewrite whole email verification in Laravel 5.7 ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment. The new trait sends [this email](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php), which currently cannot be queued.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no built in way, but you can do it easily by extending and overriding.

First, create a new notification that extends the built-in notification, and also implements the ShouldQueue contract (to enable queuing). The following class assumes you create a notification at `app/Notifications/VerifyEmailQueued.php`:

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

class VerifyEmailQueued extends VerifyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    // Nothing else needs to go here unless you want to customize
    // the notification in any way.
}
```

Now you need to tell the framework to use your custom notification instead of the default one. You do this by overriding the `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` on your `User` model. This simply changes which notification gets sent out.

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\VerifyEmailQueued);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charn!

Comment: this is so much simpler than the accepted answer, and it works

Comment: This working, but when click on verification link (sent by email) it redirects to 403, Invalid Signature page. (Laravel 6)

Comment: @IrfanGondal The notification is now going to be queued, so the URL in the notification will be built using your APP_URL in your environment file. That APP_URL will need to match the final url. So, for example, if your site is on `https`, you will need to ensure your APP_URL is also `https`.

Answer (score 13):

Yes! It's possible. And to do that you will have to rewrite the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` in your `App\User`. This method is provided by the `Illuminate\Auth\MustVerfiyEmail` trait. The method `sendEmailVerificationNotification` notifies the created `user` by sending an Email as defined in the `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail` Notification class.

```
// This is the code defined in the sendEmailVerificationNotification
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new Notifications\VerifyEmail);
}
```

You can change this method to not notify directly the user. You will have to define a `Job` which you will dispath in the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method instead of notifying the created user.

In the `Job` class you will create a `handle` method where you can send the email to the `user`, but you must provide the `$user` to the Job which can be performed by passing it as a parameter to the `dispatch` method like this:

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    VerifyEmail::dispatch($this);
}
```

`$this` represents the created `user` and the `App\Jobs\VerififyEmail` job (which you will create) will receive all the parameters passed to the `dispatch` in its `__construct`

The code of the `VerifyEmail` will look like this:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

class VerifyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Here the email verification will be sent to the user
        $this->user->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, it works ! just had to rename Job class QueuedVerifyEmail because of double class name declaration.

Comment: You are welcome. Even if both class have the same name because they're in different namespace `App\Jobs\VerifyEmail` and `Illuminate\Auth\Notification\VerifyEmail`  It will not make any issue

Comment: You could have used the same class name by aliasing Laravel's class to another name like: `use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailNotification;` and in the `handle` method `$this->user->notify(new VerifyEmailNotification);`. That's a bit cleaner to my opinion, but that's just nitpicking.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is for if you gonna register a user manually in the controller.
Laravel already created the Registered event and its listener SendEmailVerificationNotification.

-first configure queue in application
in .env file update `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`.
for more queue documentation read https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues

- publish queue table by `php artisan queue:table`
- `php artisan migrate`
- `php artisan make:job EmailVerificationJob`
- in EmailVerificationJob.php add public variable

  public $user;
- in EmailVerificationJob.php constructor

  public function __construct(User $user)
  {
  $this->user = $user;
  }
- in EmailVerificationJob.php handle function write `event(new Registered($this->user))`.
- in your controller if user created successfully add this code for job to work.

  EmailVerificationJob::dispatch($user)
  ->delay(now()->addSeconds(5));
  here job delay for 5 seconds.
- at the end you must start queue worker `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` . here tries means how many times queue should try the job.

### Update#1

this solution I used in Laravel 8.

first create SendEmailVerificationNotification notification class

```
php artisan make:notification SendEmailVerificationNotification
```

app/Notifications/SendEmailVerificationNotification.php file content will be this one. here we are going to extend Laravel default SendEmailVerificationNotification class and implement should queue

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SendEmailVerificationNotification extends \Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
}
```

the last step is editing EventServiceProvider class $listen array. Comment out default notification of Registered event and add custom notification which we have created.

```
use App\Notifications\SendEmailVerificationNotification as QueuedSendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
//use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;

protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
//            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            QueuedSendEmailVerificationNotification::class
        ],
```

];

Comment: The Update#1 solution (for Laravel 8) is the right thing. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

The solution is pretty simple:

**`Steps:`**

1. Configure Queue Driver
2. Go To --> Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail
3. Implement 'ShouldQueue' interface and add a trait 'Queueable' on above mentioned class i.e. 'VerifyEmail' like this:

class VerifyEmail extends Notification implements **ShouldQueue**{
use **Queueable**;

....
....
...
}

3.That's it

**Path of interface & trait:**
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;

Please check the docs too:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#queueing-notifications

Comment: Not a great idea to modify the laravel classes, that's why solutions above suggest to do it by extending and overriding.

Comment: it is not a good idea to make changes to files in laravel vendor folder because at the next composer update command your changes on files in vendor folder will be removed.