# How to rate limit queued verification and password reset notification emails in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, rate-limiting, laravel-5.7

## Issue

Using Laravel 5.7 with Redis, I have gotten the email verification and password reset notifications to queue using the method described in Stephen Mudere's answer in  [How to send the password reset link via email using queue in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409236/how-to-send-the-password-reset-link-via-email-using-queue-in-laravel-5), but I cannot figure out how to rate-limit those particular queued notifications.  Because my application will send emails for a variety of reasons (not just these two purposes) and my email server is rate-limited to 30 emails per minute, I need to rate-limit everything on an 'email' queue.

## Background

Per the Laravel queue [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#rate-limiting), it seems fairly straighforward to do this in a job class in the handle method using

```
Redis::throttle('key')->allow(10)->every(60)->then(function () {
  // Job logic...
}, function () {
  // Could not obtain lock...

  return $this->release(10);
});
```

The problem is that I'm not using a job class, but rather a notification.  For example, for the password reset, I've created the following

```
ResetPassword Class
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

class ResetPassword extends ResetPasswordNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
}
```

which gets invoked from the User model using:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

## Approach

I have attempted to solve this by modifying the sendPasswordResetNotification function in the User model:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    Redis::throttle('email')->allow(2)->every(60)->then(function () use($token) {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }, function () {
        // Could not obtain lock...

        return $this->release(10);
    });
}
```

Note that the values for the throttle are artificially low for testing purposes.  This seems to work partially.  In the example above, if I try two successive password resets, the emails both queue and send.  When I try to send the third email (exceeding the limit of 2 per minute I've set), I get a BadMethodCallException, `"Call to undefined method App\User::release()"`.  I understand that this is because the User model doesn't have a release method, but it comes back to the problem that I'm not sure exactly where or how to use the throttling logic.  Is there a way to modify this to work, or do I need to take a totally different approach to sending these messages?

## Update: Alternative approach that fails for a different reason

I switched from using a notification to using a Job so that I could use the Redis::throttle per the documentation.  To set up the job to queue a message, I used the approach from [How to queue Laravel 5.7 "email verification" email sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644934/how-to-queue-laravel-5-7-email-verification-email-sending/52647112#52647112).  This worked fine for sending queued emails.  I then tried to throttle the jobs going onto the queue.  Here's my complete approach:

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class QueuedVerifyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Redis::throttle('email')->allow(2)->every(60)->then(function () {
            $this->user->notify(new VerifyEmail);
        }, function() {
           return $this->release(10);
        });
    }
}
```

These go onto the queue, but then fail.  In the stack trace is the following:
`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'App\Jobs\Redis' not found in /home/vagrant/code/myapp/app/Jobs/QueuedVerifyEmail.php:27`

I can't figure out why it's looking for the Redis facade in App\Jobs when I have a use statement to define the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I got it working

The solution under "Update: Alternative approach" ended up working.  I'm not sure why it was failing (perhaps something was cached?), but it now appears to work correctly.